# Accellerated Mobile Pages (Amp) : amp-ad for doubleclick

Tags: amp-html

im trying to get around the composition of amps ad-compononent for doubleclick.
To be used id needs to have the attribute data-slot defined, like in this  (the only available) example:

```html
 <amp-ad width=320 height=50
 type="doubleclick"
 data-slot="/4119129/mobile_ad_banner">
</amp-ad>]]>
```

My Question is, if anybody knows, how to generate that data-slot and/or what components are in it, because i don´t get it?

Thank you very much for your help!

additional links:  https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/ads/doubleclick.md
https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/ads/doubleclick.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it:

```
<amp-ad width=300 height=250
type="doubleclick"
data-slot="/advertUrl/advertZone">
json='{"targeting":{insert targeting here}
</amp-ad>
```

Comment: Would be good to know what advertUrl and advertZone is. Had to test around: In DFP you can generate the Code. Either for Mobile, the data-slot is what will be generated. For 'Google Publisher Tag' look for `googletag.defineSlot('/foo/bar', [300, 250], 'di...` and use the `/foo/bar`. The other options dont matter I found.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is the example](https://support.google.com/dfp_sb/answer/1651549?hl=en) of JS generated DFP code, you can easy find/google how to generate it. 
Look at this line:

```
googletag.defineSlot("/1234/travel/asia/food", [728, 90], "div-gpt-ad-123456789-0")
```

**data-slot** is first **defineSlot** parameter from js code,
so AMP code must be like this:

```
<amp-ad width=320 height=50
 type="doubleclick"
 data-slot="/1234/travel/asia/food">
</amp-ad>
```

Comment: At first thank you for your help. But what i don´t get, is what the number at the beginning is, is that the network-id or is it the AdvertUrl or something else? And why do you set your targetings into the data slot whilst in google's example its the format?